# Find all combinations of elements in a list that sum up to a value

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list of random length, like:

```
L = [190, 20, 80, 200, 10].
```

Is there any way to get all possible combinations of elements in an output list, so that their sum is less or equal than a given value?

E.g. find_elements(MaxValue, InputList, OutputList).

Possible solutions for MaxValue = 200:

```
OutputList = [190, 10]
OutputList = [200]
OuputList = [20, 80, 10]
```

My code looks like this so far:

```
solutions(_, [], [], _).

solutions(MaxValue, [H|T], OutputList, Acc):-
    Z is H + Acc,
    Z > MaxValue,
    solutions(MaxValue, T, OutputList, Acc), !.

solutions(MaxValue, [H|T], [H|T2], Acc):-
    Z is H + Acc,
    Z =< MaxValue,
    solutions(MaxValue, T, T2, Z).

solutions(MaxValue, Inputlist, OutputList):-
    solutions(MaxValue, Inputlist, OutputList, 0).
```

If I call
`solutions(200, [190, 250, 3, 4, 180, 10], X)`
I get:

```
X = [190, 3, 4]
```

But `X = [3, 4, 180]` is also true and `X = [180, 10]` too. I'd like to have them all as solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to recursively traverse the list using an accumulator variable that adds up elements from left to right, but it's not what I want. If I used MaxValue = 200, I'd get OutputList = [190]. But there are also other element combinations that satisfy this, for example OutputList = [20, 80, 10].

Comment: Edit your question and show your coding attempt and where you're stuck.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code. Thank you.

Comment: [A hint](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Find%20all%20combination%20that%20sums%20up.pl). You may want to tweak it cause this will give you every order of all combinations ;)

Comment: Thank you, Rafalon, that's all I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick implementation could be this:

```
subset([], []).
subset([H|T], [H|T1]):-
  subset(T,T1).
subset([_|T],T1):-
  subset(T, T1).

solve(MaxVal,Lin,Lout):-
    subset(Lin,Lout),
    sumlist(Lout,Val),
    Val < MaxVal.
```

Query:

```
?- solve(200,[190, 20, 80, 200, 10],L).
L = [190]
L = [20, 80, 10]
L = [20, 80]
L = [20, 10]
L = [20]
L = [80, 10]
L = [80]
L = [10]
L = []
```

So simply you can find all the subset and then check if the sum of the list is less than the value `MaxVal`